# What is the difference between those two calculations? Drude model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics

I stumbled upon 2 questions that I cannot really understand the physical difference between;

> **Question 1:**
>
> Use Drude model and its assumptions: A metal is found in constant temperature and an external electric field $ \overrightarrow{E} $. A valence electron collide with a ion and then colide once again with another ion. Find the average energy loss of the electron in the second collision, given that the time distribution is $ f\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{\tau}e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} $.

This is not too hard a calculation, and the answer is

$$ \langle\varepsilon\rangle=\frac{\left(eE\tau\right)^{2}}{m_{e}} $$

(where $ \langle\varepsilon\rangle $ denotes the expectation).

Now there's question 2 which looks familiar but not the same:

> **Question 2:**
>
> Use Drude model and its assumptions: A metal is found in constant temperature and an external electric field $ \overrightarrow{E} $. A valence electron collides with an ion *and after time $t$ * collides with another ion. Find the average energy loss of the electron in the second collision.

The answer for the second question is :

$$ \frac{\left(eEt\right)^{2}}{2m_{e}} $$

I do not understand what is actually the difference between the questions (what is the difference from the physics point of view)

I'll show my calculations for the first question:

By Newton's second law:

$$ -\frac{e\overrightarrow{E}}{m_{e}}=\frac{d\overrightarrow{v}}{dt} $$

and thus

$$ \overrightarrow{v}\left(t\right)=-\frac{e\overrightarrow{E}}{m_{e}}t+\overrightarrow{v_{0}} $$

Where $v_0 $ is the velocity between collisions (I guess it's just the thermal velocity, and thus the expectation of this velocity is zero).

The energy loss in the collision, is due to the energy gained by the electric field, that is the energy:

$$ \varepsilon\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{2}m_{e}\left(-\frac{e\overrightarrow{E}}{m_{e}}t\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{2m_{e}}\left(eE\right)^{2}t^{2} $$

and thus for the average energy we want to calculate the expectation. That is:

$$\langle\varepsilon\rangle=\langle\frac{1}{2m_{e}}\left(eE\right)^{2}t^{2}\rangle=\frac{1}{2m_{e}}\left(eE\right)^{2}\langle t^{2}\rangle=\frac{1}{2m_{e}}\left(eE\right)^{2}\intop_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2}}{\tau}e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}dt=\frac{\left(eE\tau\right)^{2}}{m_{e}} $$

I'm not sure how exactly to do the calculations of the second question, because I'm not sure what should I do different (and how exactly are we supposed to calculate the expectation of the energy when the distribution is not given)

A clarification would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first problem, the collision time is a random variable, and you're given a PDF telling you how this variable is distributed. The collision could take place at any time after $t=0$.

In the second problem, the collision time is definite — we know the collision happens at a certain time $t=\tau$. If it helps, you could think about the collision time as a random variable with PDF
\begin{align}
f(t) = \delta(t - \tau),
\end{align}
where $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta distribution. If you repeat the calculation of the first problem using this distribution function, you will get the answer of the second problem.

Comment: Can I think about the collision time of the second problem as a constant random variable, so that the expectation of $t^2$ is just $t^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, that works.